# sql delete rows with 1 column duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a microsoft sql 2005 db table where the entire row is not duplicate, but a column is duplicated.

1  aaa
1  bbb
1  ccc
2  abc
2  def

How can i delete all the rows but 1 that have the first column duplicated?

For clarification I need to get rid of the second, third and fifth rows.

Comment: Is it for a one-off maintenance/migration purpose or it will be reused programmatic-ally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following query in sql server 2005

```
WITH T AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS rnum,* FROM dbo.Table_1)
DELETE FROM T WHERE rnum>1
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's call these the id and the Col1 columns.

```
DELETE myTable T1
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM myTable T2
   WHERE T2.id = T1.id AND T2.Col1 > T1.Col1)
```

Edit: As pointed out by Andomar, the above doesn't get rid of exact duplicate cases, where both id and Col1 are the same in different rows. 
These can be handled as follow:

(note: whereby the above query is **generic SQL**, the following applies to **MSSQL 2005** and above)
It uses the [**Common Table Expression**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) (CTE) feature, along with ROW_NUMBER() function to produce a distinctive row value.  It is essentially the same construct as the above except that it now works with a "table" (CTEs are mostly like a table) which has a truly distinct identifier key.
Note that by removing "AND T2.Col1 = T1.Col1", we produce a query which can handle both types of duplicates (id-only duplicates and both Id and Col1 duplicates) in a single query, i.e. in a similar fashion that Hamadri's solution (the PARTITION in his/her CTE serves the same purpose as the subquery in this solution, essentially the same amount of work is done). Depending on the situation, it may be preferable, performance-wise or other, to handle the situation in two steps.

```
WITH T AS
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id, Col1) AS rn, id, Col1 FROM MyTable)
DELETE T AS T1
WHERE EXISTS
   (SELECT * 
    FROM T AS T2
    WHERE T2.id = T1.id AND T2.Col1 = T1.Col1
      AND T2.rn > T1.rn
   )
```

Comment: @Andomar.  right you are (though you mean Id and Col1).  See edit with a CTE construct which handles this case).

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE tableName as ta
WHERE col2 NOT IN (SELECT MIN(col2) FROM tableName AS t2 GROUP BY col1)
```

Make sure the sub select returns the rows you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DELETE FROM <TABLE_NAME_HERE> WHERE <SECOND_COLUMN_NAME_HERE> IN ("bbb","abc","def");
```

Comment: hum... I hope muhan was after a more generic solution ;-)

Comment: He dint specify if he wanted to delete randomly or lexicographically.
so.. um second, third and fifth deleted *grin*

Comment: Yes that example table was just an example. My table is much larger and many more duplicates.

Comment: mhan - what is the rule that is used to decide which row to keep?

Answer (score 0):

SQL server is not my native SQL database, but maybe something like this? The idea is to get the duplicates and delete the ones with the larger ROW_NUMBER. This should leave only the first one. I dont know if this is what you want or if it will work, but the logic seems sound

```
DELETE T1
FROM T1 T2
WHERE T1.Col1 = T2.col1
AND T1.ROW_NUMBER() > T2.ROW_NUMBER()
```

Please feel free to correct me if SQL server cant handle that kind of treatment :)

Answer (score 0):

--Another idea using ROW_NUMBER()

```
Delete MyTable
Where Id IN
(
    Select T.Id FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueColumn ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber FROM MyTable
    )T
    WHERE T.RowNumber > 1
)
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything to what the accepted answer offers, so what is the point of posting it?